# Spring Boot - @MockBean Creating Duplicate in Test Case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I attempting to "mock" a bean in `@SpringBootTest`.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SalesSummaryServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private SalesSummaryMapper summmaryMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    private SalesSummaryService salesSummmaryService;

    @Test
    public void testGetMonthlySummary() {

        // Removed for brevity

        given(this.summmaryMapper.selectByPropDate(testSchema, testProp, testDate, testEnd)).willReturn(List.of(testSum, testSum));     
        var res = this.salesSummmaryService.getMonthlySummary(test, testProp, testDate.getMonthValue(), testDate.getYear());

        // Removed for brevity
        
        
        
    }

}
```

However, the test fails (Application Context fails to load) because no unique bean can be found:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.midamcorp.data.dal.SalesSummaryMapper' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: salesSummaryMapper,com.midamcorp.data.dal.SalesSummaryMapper#0
```

The class under test is a basic `@Service` implementation:

```
@Service
public class SalesSummaryServiceImpl implements SalesSummaryService {

    private SalesSummaryMapper salesSumMapper;
    
    @Autowired
    public SalesSummaryServiceImpl(SalesSummaryMapper salesSumMapper) {
        this.salesSumMapper = salesSumMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SaleSummary> getMonthlySummary(PropType propType, String propId, int monthVal, int yearVal) {
        var startDate = LocalDate.of(yearVal, monthVal, 1);
        var endDate = startDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        return this.salesSumMapper.selectByPropDate(propType.getSchema(), propId, startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

The `SaleSummaryMapper` dependency is a simple MyBatis mapper:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface SalesSummaryMapper {
}
```

I understand the basic error (e.g. Spring cannot determine which bean to use as two could satisify the dependency). What I do not understand is *why* the "real" mapper bean is not being replaced by the `@MockBean` when, per the docs: "Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock". What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to test this test, don't use `@SpringBootTest`. Just create an instance of the service, manually mock the dependency and run the test. A lot faster and easier. Only use `@SpringBootTest` if you want to do a full integration test.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be related to the way how MyBatis register beans in the spring context. The interface `SalesSummaryMapper` is not the type of a bean created in spring context. From MyBatis documentation example I see that mapper is actually of type `MapperFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper.UserMapper" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I assume that similar thing happens when you use any kind of scanner to register interfaces marked with `@Mapper` annotation.

So the main reason why the `@MockBean` doesn't replace mapper is because they are not of the same type.

Edit: I take the above back. Beans will be same type because `MapperFactoryBean` implements Spring's `FactoryBean`. It may be that at the moment when a mocked bean is created there is no bean created by the factory yet?

You can first verify this by replacing your mapper with an actual `@Component` bean. If that works then you should try to mock using names rather than types.

In MyBatis documentation you can read:

> Discovered mappers will be named using Spring default naming strategy
> for autodetected components (see the Spring reference document(Core
> Technologies -Naming autodetected components-)). That is, if no
> annotation is found, it will use the uncapitalized non-qualified class
> name of the mapper. But if either a @Component or a JSR-330 @Named
> annotation is found it will get the name from the annotation. Notice
> that you can set the annotation attribute to
> org.springframework.stereotype.Component, javax.inject.Named (if you
> have JSE 6) or to your own annotation (that must be itself annotated)
> so the annotation will work both as a marker and as a name provider.

Based on above the potential solution can be to mark the mapper additionaly as named `@Component`:

```
@Mapper
@Component("salesSummaryMapper")
public interface SalesSummaryMapper {
}
```

and in the test use `@Qualifier`

```
@MockBean
@Qualifier("salesSummaryMapper")
private SalesSummaryMapper summmaryMapper;
```

Comment: The factory bean will create the said bean. Which is probably cause of having 2 beans here at that point.